# SQL Server : Change dateformat for every connection

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to change `dateformat` from *DMY* to *YMD* only for new connections?

I tried a LOGON trigger using `SET DATEFORMAT YMD` but always the default *DMY* is back.

So I want to keep the default *DMY* into database however for new sessions (connections) I want to change to *YMD*.

Comment: From the docs: `SET DATEFORMAT` overrides the implicit date format setting of [SET LANGUAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql), so you can change it to acheive that.

Comment: For current session is OK but What I need is the changed DATEFORMAT for new sessions in a automated way, that's the reason to mention a LOGON trigger

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is tied to the language of your server which you can look up like this:

```
USE [master]
GO

SELECT * FROM [syslanguages]
```

then you need to run sp_config with the langid from the first query

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 'langid'
GO;
RECONFIGURE
GO;
```

Comment: Thanks. However I could have further problems changing whole language, I only want to change DATEFORMAT, Any other way?

Comment: I never tried it and I hope you are not going to do it in production, but you you can try to manually update that dateformat column

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the solution.
SQL management studio gets the data format from your local windows settings.

- Click on the clock (windows)
- Click on Change data and time settings...
- Click on Change calendar settings
- Go to Date tab
- Change the Short date format to: yyyy-MM-dd

that is it.